# Best questions and answers from 4th quarter of 2020

Tags: discussion, best-of

Some Stack Exchange sites, such as [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), [Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10763/89356), [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) and [Spanish Language SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nominaciones+a+la+mejor+respuesta), have (or had, as the case may be) a tradition of trying to identify the best questions and answers from the last quarter. These are contributions that may be posted on a blog or a Twitter account if the site has one; otherwise they are a nice collection of the best contributions made in a community.

In addition to identifying material that can be used to promote the site elsewhere, such a list of nominations can also be used to highlight high-quality contributions that did not get a lot of votes when they were posted.

So what are the rules?

- Find **great questions and great answers** from the last quarter. There are [just over 300 questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2020-10-01..2020-12-31+is%3Aq) and [more than 550 answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2020-10-01..2020-12-31+is%3Aa) to choose from [1].
- You can nominate multiple posts per answer.
- Some sort of explanation *why* the nominated post is particularly good would be worth adding. This can give future contributors an idea of how to write up good questions or answers.

[1] This is a marked increase compared to the second quarter (264 questions and another 460 answers) and the third quarter (204 questions and 408 answers).

Answer (score 2):

There were a lot of interesting questions this quarter! I selected two that I particularly liked:

#### [Spring forward, fall back](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43512/spring-forward-fall-back)

**A question by Luke Sawczak, answered by himself**

I find this question very interesting because it is one of these expressions that are hard to translate without losing the poetry in it. And most of all, I find the answer very clever. :)

#### [How is this linguistic concept called in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43457/how-is-this-linguistic-concept-called-in-french)

**A question by chaero, answered by Greg**

Because sometimes, we forget that FSE "*[is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the French language](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)*", I thought it would be nice to underline a question about linguistics, especially from someone who was studying Russian. It's a nice mix. The discussed concept is very interesting, and after reading, you really feel like you've learned something. That's what Stack Exchange is all about.