# Best questions and answers from the 2nd quarter of 2021

Tags: discussion, best-of

As I have mentioned in [previous similar posts](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), some Stack Exchange sites, such as [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), [Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10763/89356), [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) and [Spanish Language SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nominaciones+a+la+mejor+respuesta), have (or had, as the case may be) a tradition of trying to identify the best questions and answers from the last quarter. These are contributions that may be posted on a blog or a Twitter account if the site has one; otherwise they are a nice collection of the best contributions made in a community.

In addition to identifying material that can be used to promote the site elsewhere, such a list of nominations can also be used to highlight high-quality contributions that did not get a lot of votes when they were posted.

So what are the rules?

- Find **great questions and great answers** from the last quarter. There are [just over 340 questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-04-01..2021-07-31+is%3Aq) and [more than 580 answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-04-01..2021-07-31+is%3Aa) to choose from [1].
- You can nominate multiple posts per answer.
- Some sort of explanation *why* the nominated post is particularly good would be worth adding. This can give future contributors an idea of how to write up good questions or answers.

[1] This is an increase compared to the last period for which I created a "best-of" question, i.e. [the fourth quarter of 2020](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/823/11052). Numberwise, the health of our site appears to be increasing.

Comment: Do we have to deal with the question and the totality of its answers? The problem is that questions sometimes are interesting/good.. but attract multiple answers some of which are wrong, or bad, with just one that is good and stands out.

Comment: @None I'm looking for great questions with great answers, great unanswered question and great answers that have received fewer upvotes than they deserve.

Comment: What I mean is how to deal with a question that has multiple answers, some of which being bad/wrong...  but one is good or outstanding. Do we have to state what answer we want to draw attention to?

Comment: @None You can link to specific answers that you want to highlight.

Answer (score 2):

[Can "parce que" be followed by a noun phrase, instead of a finite clause?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/46889/358)
A precise, well asked and documented question and an answer that tackles grammar and vocabulary and that is open to regional variations.

---

https://french.stackexchange.com/a/47039/358

How a very narrow question about a very abstruse text can nevertheless lead to  a very open answer that makes us travel through a lot of French vocabulary and meanings.

---

[In French, can an intransitive verb have an indirect objects](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/47093/358)
Probably good for promotion, helps to compare quality with other sites on French language.